# PDF form email fields need to be sent to all three recipients

Tags: forms, email, pdf

I have a PDF form with 3 different email fields to be filled out (named mailto, mailcc and buyer). What do I have to do to let the completed PDF be sent to all three email adresses after pressing the SEND button?

I have tried this code but it sends only to the address from the "mailto" field and I was unable to extract and add the mailcc and buyer field information.

```
allgood();  
function allgood()  
{  
 var adr="";  
 for (var i=0;i<this.numFields;i++)  
 {  
  var fName=this.getNthFieldName(i);  
  var f=this.getField(fName);  
  if (f.name == "mailto")
  {  
    if(f.value != "") 
    { 
      adr=f.value; 
    } 
  }  
 }  
 if (adr=="") 
 {  
  app.alert("Bitte E-Mail-Adresse angeben!"); 
 }  
 else  
 { 
   this.mailDoc({bUI: true, cTo: adr}); 
 }  
}
```

Hope anyone can help.

[link to view the document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B73TJkeiDkxLSVNtaGJkOEFjRE0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I really wonder why that function loops through all the fields to test whether there is a field named "mailto"… "if(this.getField("mailto") != null )" does exactly the same…

Comment: thanks - it was copied from another forum

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of RTFM (in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the Adobe website) states that cTo is the semicolon-delimited list of receipients. The situation is the same for cCc and cBcc.

Answer (score 0):

RTMF was not an option, that's why I tried this forum. But anyway here is the solution (with modifications) for anybody who is looking for a similar topic.

```js
//Email Variables  
var cToAddr = this.getField("supplierEmail").value+ ";" + this.getField("internalservicesEmail").value;  
var cCCAddr = this.getField("requestorEmail").value+ ";" + this.getField("managerEmail").value+ ";" + this.getField("buyerEmail").value;  
var cSubLine = "Here comes the SUBJECT";  
var cBody = "Here comes the BODY TEXT.";  
  
//Submission Script  
this.mailDoc({  
    bUI: true,  
    cTo: cToAddr,  
    cCc: cCCAddr,  
    cSubject: cSubLine,  
    cMsg: cBody  
})
```